# Salesforce formula showing negative number/time between two dates

Tags: formula, custom-object, formula-field, custom-field, email2case

I have a business requirement to show the total number of working hours (Mon-Friday 8.30am to 5pm) between the case creation date and current time (NOW() if the case is open) or closing time if the case is closed. The timer should stop after 5pm and re-start again the following day at 8.30am. For example, if the case is created after 5pm, its sla should begin from 8.30am the following working day.

I created the following two formula fields for this purpose:

Calculate_Time_Elapsed__c

```
ROUND( 8.5 * (
( 5 * FLOOR( ( DATEVALUE( IF(TEXT(Status__c) = "Closed",Closed__c,NOW()) ) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8) ) / 7) +
MIN(5,
MOD( DATEVALUE( IF(TEXT(Status__c) = "Closed",Closed__c,NOW()) ) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8), 7) +
MIN( 1, 24 / 8.5 * ( MOD( IF(TEXT(Status__c) = "Closed",Closed__c,NOW()) - DATETIMEVALUE( '1900-01-08 07:30:00' ), 1 ) ) )
)
)
-
( 5 * FLOOR( ( DATEVALUE( Opened__c ) - DATE( 1900, 1, 8) ) / 7) +
MIN( 5,
MOD( DATEVALUE( Opened__c) - DATE( 1996, 1, 1), 7 ) +
MIN( 1, 24 / 8.5 * ( MOD(Opened__c- DATETIMEVALUE( '1900-01-08 07:30:00' ), 1) ) )
)
)
),
2 )
```

Time_Elapsed__c

```
FLOOR(Calculate_Time_Elapsed__c)
+ MOD(Calculate_Time_Elapsed__c,1)*0.60
```

The only issue with these formula fields is that it displays negative number for cases that are created between 11.59pm and 8.29am. They display the correct sla/number of any other case that are created outside these hours.